# How to apply a time limit to a web service call in ColdFusion?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I'm working on a system that calls an external web service to obtain data. It appears that when something fails in the web service, the caller is left hanging and the template never ends.

There is a CFSETTING REQUESTTIMEOUT in the calling template, but it does not seem to be applied to the web service call. The calling code uses CFSCRIPT and I am uncomfortable with the syntax. Can someone advise me how to apply a timeout to the following code?

```
ws = CreateObject("webservice", "http://#trim(arguments.RemoteSite)#",{wsversion="2"});
ret = ws.GetJData("#arguments.clubid#", #datepart('yyyy',arguments.StartDate)#, #datepart('m',arguments.StartDate)#);
```

Comment: There's a timeout option on the createobject call, according to the docs (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CreateObjectwebserviceobject.html). Did you try that? The wording is vague, so not sure if it's a timeout on all requests to the web service, or just the initial WSDL fetch. Worth trying though. TBH I'd just use `<cfhttp>` for this sorta thing. And it has a timeout option that def works.

Comment: `<cfinvoke>` has a timeout option as well. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfinvoke.html

Comment: I didn't write this component, but in the absence of any definitive info I plan to rewrite it to use cfinvoke. I find the combo of cfscript, oo notation and poor documentation pretty intimidating!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that you can set a timeout in the argStruct when creating the WSDL object. Which by default is 0 (no timeout); If you set a timeout you will also need exception handling because the web service call will throw a timeout exception.

```
// Define webservice config
webServiceConfig = {
  wsversion="2",
  timeout=10
};
// Initialise wsdl webservice
ws = CreateObject(
  "webservice",
  "http://#trim(arguments.RemoteSite)#",
  webServiceConfig
);
try
{
  // Execute method
  ret = ws.GetJData(
    "#arguments.clubid#",
    #datepart('yyyy',arguments.StartDate)#,
    #datepart('m',arguments.StartDate)#
  );
} catch (any e)
{
  // An exception is thrown on timeout - handle it here:
  ret = "";
}
```

I tested this pattern on [CF Fiddle](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=f9e3812a-d534-40f0-aff8-2f158c53d9c6/e9f966dc-d8e7-417e-ae64-ac13df66c18b/0f95613c-bf67-437e-b33a-253dd885fc04.cfm) if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this for me. Ordinarily I would do exactly what you showed me, but I recently learned from the web service developer, that timeouts on web services written in ColdFusion are quite problematic. He indicated that in spite of timeouts, when the web service fails, the CF code sometimes still hangs. So adding a timeout to the call is probably not going to fix the original problem. Instead, he has provided me with a proxy written in ASP that will get around this issue. I guess this is why there is little on the Internet about timeouts in CF for web services.